# message.guild.createChannel is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello I'm making a ticket bot for my server.
But I'm getting error like `message.guild.createChannel is not a function`

The code

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + `openticket`)) {
    const reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
    if (message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c === `ticket-${message.author.id}`)) return message.channel.send(`You already opened a ticket.`);
    message.guild.createChannel(`ticket-${message.author.id}`, "text").then(c => {
        let role2 = message.guild.roles.find("name", "@everyone");
        c.overwritePermissions(role, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            READ_MESSAGES: true
        });
        c.overwritePermissions(role2, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            READ_MESSAGES: false
        });
        c.overwritePermissions(message.author, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            READ_MESSAGES: true
        });
        message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Your ticket is opened, #${c.name}.`);
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0xCF40FA)
        .addField(`Hey ${message.author.username}!`, `Your Ticket is opened.`)
        .setTimestamp();
        c.send({ embed: embed });
        message.delete();
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

İ think the code is too old. I got this code from my friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be a mix between `discord.js v11` and `discord.js v12` version.

`v12` introduced [Managers](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseManager).

To create a channel on a guild, you have to use the [GuildChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager), this is the `v12` way to do it ([see GuildChannelManager.create method documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create)) :

```js
message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.id}`, { type: 'text' }).then(c => {
    ...
});
```

[Useful guide that shows changes between `v11` and `v12`.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)